Horror Anthology
This movie came out a while ago. 
It had three movies in it that I can remember. 
One of them was about someone who cooked in a restaurant. He cut his finger and got blood in the food and it was served to people. Everyone who ate it liked the food and he began doing it more often. He ends up sleeping with his coworker and she gets pregnant. At the end of that movie, she reveals she is pregnant and I don't remember if she cut his tongue out but it sounds familiar. 
Another movie is about a woman who's boyfriend or husband is out of town and she is stalked by someone via her webcam. The person tortures her with various things, including the fact that her boyfriend is cheating on her, and she ends up committing suicide. 
The last one I remember is kind of fuzzy, but I do remember that a man ends up dead beside his car, covered in sea weed. I think it had something to do with donating to a kid in another country and then pulling the funds?
I think this may have been in the movie, but it could be just mixed in, but I think I remember that after every movie there were two men talking and at one point they are eating meat - I think after the cannibal one.
It wasn't a series because I remember getting it from Redbox.

Welcome to Movies & TV! Please try to add anything that may help identification. When was it released? What time period was it about? What country was it likely from? What language? Are there recognisable actors or characters you can give? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. You might also want to provide a more descriptive question title.

Yes, approximate year and country might help, but it's a fairly detailed plot description. It's not a movie, though, so where\how the OP watched it might also be of use.

What is the link between the three movies? Same actors ? Same title ? Anything else ? Because stories seem really different

@Lordofdark Isn't that the point of an anthology?

Might you be thinking of the horror anthology series 'The Unknown'?
It premiered in 2012 on Sony Pictures' 'Crackle' network, and, if you watch the trailer, seems to feature one segment about a chef who drips his own blood into his food (look around the 50 sec mark)
The Unknown Trailer
